# Override default ASP.NET MVC message in FluentValidation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I get the validation message "The value xxx is not valid for yyy". It happens when I post incorrect value for double type. I have no idea how to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't something that FluentValidation has the ability to override - the extensibility model for MVC's validation is somewhat limited in many places, and I've not been able to find a way to override this particular message.

An alternative approach you could use is to define two properties on your view model - one as a string, and one as a nullable double. You would use the string property for MVC binding purposes, and the double property would perform a conversion (if it can). You can then use this for validation:

```
public class FooModel {
   public string Foo { get; set; }

   public double? ConvertedFoo {
      get {
          double d;
          if(double.TryParse(Foo, out d)) {
             return d;
          }
          return null;
      }
   }
}


public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<FooModel> {
   public FooValidator() {
      RuleFor(x => x.ConvertedFoo).NotNull();
      RuleFor(x => x.ConvertedFoo).GreaterThan(0).When(x => x.ConvertedFoo != null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to contact with ASP.NET MVC team about it?

Comment: Yes, I raised it several times during the preview period for MVC2, but it was never changed.

Comment: Let's try it once more: http://forums.asp.net/p/1721550/4601626.aspx/1?p=True&t=634518558226229075

Comment: As war as I know, this is not even MVC. Those messages are deep down in the .net framework.See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587816/how-to-change-the-errormessage-for-int-model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: this error still going in netcore, after all these years, we need to use this workaround? or there is another approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.WithMessage()` method to customize the error message:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Foo)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithMessage("Put your custom message here");
```

and if you want to use localized messages with resources:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Foo)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithLocalizedMessage(() => MyLocalizedMessage.FooRequired);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The error appears when ASP.NET tries to convert string to double