# DataTypeAttribute is showing the wrong message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I create the following attribute:

```
public class SpecificDataTypeAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{
    public SpecificDataType(DataType dataType, string field)
        : base(dataType)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = string.Format("{0} {1}", field, Messages.SpecificDataTypeAttribute);
    }
}
```

And use like:

```
[SpecificDataType(DataType.DateTime, "Initial date")]
public DateTime? InitialDate { get; set; }
```

So, the message that is in `Messages.SpecificDataTypeAttribute` is `"is in a incorrect format."`. When i input a wrong date in InitialDate, i got the default error: `"The value '12' is not valid for InitialDate."`. Why? I put the breakpoint and the code is calling the SpecificDataType ctor.

Comment: I'd guess that it's because `DateTime?` is in fact `Nullable<DateTime>` and not plain old `DateTime`. See if it works if you declare the initial date as `public DateTime InitialDate {get;set;}`

Comment: Nothing was changed. Keeps with same error.

Comment: Ah, I didn't really read your question with comprehension :) My previous comment can be scratched. Anyway, the most I have now is a murky theory and no idea how to circumvent the issue, so I'll leave the topic to people smarter than me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in wrong direction - in asp.net mvc, `DataTypeAttribute` does not define validation rules. It is more or less like [UIHintAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) - helps to specify which template to use when rendering property in edit or display modes.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9582363/639343) to learn about customizing validation messages for system types

The value for `PropertyValueInvalid` is formatted, with {0} replaced by invalid value, and {1} with property name. So you can define it as

> {1} is in invalid format

Comment: With this way i change the default message. But how can i put the field name in the message?

Comment: I got a problem. In VS works fine, but when i publish the project in the test machine, keeps showing the default message.

Comment: Solved. I change the `Build Action` of the `Messages.resx` to `Content`.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 4 is possible to localize default error message. http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/03/31/localizing-default-error-messages-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-form.aspx