# ASP.NET MVC - Default Range validation error message not being overridden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, rangevalidator

Say I have a model property like this:

```
[Range(1, 31, ErrorMessage = "O dia de fechamento deve possuir valores entre 1 e 31")]
public int DataInicial { get; set; }
```

Even with a custom error message set on the annotation, I'm still getting the default error message for the Range annotation "Please enter a value less than or equal to 31.", when I type something like "32" or more at the `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataInicial)` field.

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587816/how-to-change-the-errormessage-for-int-model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc) post, but I think if you can set custom messages at annotation level, It should work without setting an App_GlobalResources and a .resx file, setting third-party libraries or whatever... I know that adding a .resx file and put all those validation strings there, is a "best-practice", but...

So, where I could be wrong, since the messages are not showing correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: client side or server side validation?

Comment: Client-side validation (the one that occurs before POSTing the form). I got "Please enter a value less than or equal to 31." when I type "32" into the form field which have Range validation, as I said above. Where do I need to change to customize this message?

Comment: 4 years later this is still an issue.
I am seeing this error message:
  Please enter a value greater than or equal to 1
with this decoration on an int:
 [Range(1, 9999, ErrorMessage = "Attribute Number must be between 1 and 9999"]

Inspecting my page I see this:
data-val-range="Attribute Number must be between 1 and 9999"

So unobtrusive validation should be working but it isn't.
Interestingly I also have this validation:
data-val-number="The field Code must be a number."

Yet when I enter a letter I still see the same error:
Please enter a value greater than or equal to 1

Answer (score -1):

I was running into the same issue and experimented a little.  Just learning MVC myself and it wasn't too obvious, but the solution seems nice and makes sense.  The issue just comes down to which validation attribute gets triggered.

I found `ErrorMessage` is specific to the validation it is associated with.

A simple example should make it real clear...

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="xxx may not be blank.")]
[Range(0.0,1000.0,ErrorMessage="The value entered must be 0 to 1000.00")]
public virtual double xxx ()  // snip...
```

If empty, upon validation you will get "xxx may not be blank". While a value has been entered but not valid you should see the other error  "The value entered...".

Comment: The question is about the custom error message not overriding the default error message for Range. Your answer has nothing to do with this question.