# ASP.NET Core 5 -a way to check primitive datatype or change error message

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a small issue: I try to implement data validation in a smart way using the `ApiController` attribute to drop out `ModelState.IsValid` in every endpoint.

But with this feature, I would want to change error message for simple primitive types as integer etc.. - maybe in different language

Actually it looks like this:

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPqRJ.png)

I also use FluentValidation but with this addon I understand that is not for simple types, but for more complex ones.

I have no idea how I can hook this problem up.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Hi @byczy, if you use `[ApiController]`, it will get model validation without hitting the method. It no need use ModelState.IsValid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with fluent validation it is absolutely possible to create validator for simple types as well such as int and string.

You just have to write a custom validator for your object. In case you only need a simple string or int than create an object with that property for which you can write the validation.

Take a look at this one: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/fluent-validation-aspnet-core/

Comment: But how about endpoint ActionResult getbyid([FromRoute]int id) ? Is it still possible to get and check it is int value type from uri?

Comment: In case there you want to allow only positive non null values than you can set validation attributes for the property, which allows you to customize the message. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587816/how-to-change-the-errormessage-for-int-model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc