# jQuery On clear Button remove html Tag

Tags: jquery, button, reset

Hi have a jQuery Validation on the form,

When user hits submit it generates an label tag as

```
<label for="LastName" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>
<label for="FirstName" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>
<label for="Email" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>
<label for="DOB" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>
```

I have a clear Button on the from when clicked 
it does the below stuff

```
$(':input','#myform')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected')
$("#DOB").removeAttr('value');
```

But i also want to remove the labels generated with the validation.
I tried something like this

```
$(':input','#myform')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected')
$("#DOB").removeAttr('value') 
$( "label[for='LastName']" ).remove()
$( "label[for='FirstName']" ).remove()
$( "label[for='Email']" ).remove();
```

But it didn't work.

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code but with semicolon at the end :). End it works.

```
$('#remove').click(function() {

    $("label[for='DOB']" ).remove();
    $("label[for='LastName']" ).remove();
    $("label[for='FirstName']" ).remove();
    $("label[for='Email']" ).remove();

});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/LS2bE/1/

Comment: thank you samich and Diodeus. as i said the label is auto generated with form validation. can i append or modify the data that the label is showing as "This field is required."?

Comment: It depends on where you initializing validation. If it's ASP.NET MVC - you can use attribute on the model fields `[Required(ErrorMessage="My Error message")]`. If you initializing in js - check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457032/jquery-validation-change-default-error-message. You can find here overriding messages for all fields or for specific one.

Answer (score 3):

Get them all in one go. All you need is:

```
$('.error').remove()
```