# Can't change default error message( jquery-validation plugin )

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I was using this post - [jQuery validation: change default error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457032/jquery-validation-change-default-error-message)

Here is my js code, that I added to jquer.validate.min.js

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
required: "",
remote: "1",
email: ""
});
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found :

```
     jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
     required: 'bla bla bla',
     remote: 'bla bla bla'
     });
```