# ASP.NET MVC4: Customize default validation messages

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem customizing some default validation messages in ASP.NET MVC4 page. In model class I have following property:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateField")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
```

When showing error message for `Required` attribute, everything is OK - my own customized message from ValidationMessages resource file is obtained. However, when validation fails for `DataType`, the default validation messages is shown.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `DateField` in your `DataType` attribute?

Comment: `DateField` is the name of the resource located in ValidationMessages resx file (could be as well something like "MyCustomDateValidationMessage" - if I renamed the mentioned resource).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ASP.NET validator works through jQuery validator, so interacting through JavaScript might help you.

This answer can help you, I guess: [jQuery validation: change default error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457032/jquery-validation-change-default-error-message?answertab=scoredesc)

You shouldn't override all of these parameters, of course, only ones you need.