# jquery validate: display error message only on specific method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, data-annotations

I have a field that has required validation property and also remote validation property.

I want to display the error message only if remote validation fails, and not on required property.

I can set the error message to an empty string, but i don't want to modify the ViewModel Data Annotations.

Is possible to do this only from client-side, without modifying the ViewModel properties?

```
// working hack
public class CreateViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    [Remote("IsUserNameValid", "Users", ErrorMessage = "This user name is already used")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [disable](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/490-How-to-add-and-remove-validation-rules-jQuery-validate-plugin-) the required rule. For example given a form with id "LoginForm" and a required input field with id "UserName", you can disable the required rule using either of these:

```
$("#UserName").rules("remove", "required");
$("#loginForm").validate().settings.rules["UserName"].required= false;
```

Another option is to [change the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457032/jquery-validation-change-default-error-message) to an empty string. Again you have a few options, for example:

```
$("#UserName").rules("add", {
    messages: {
        required: ""
    }
});
$("#loginForm").validate().settings.messages["UserName"].required= '';
```

In the end this is about playing with the rules and messages of the jquery validation object for the form.

Hope it helps!