# jquery validate plugin override error message for required:

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, overriding

So I have been trying to do global override for all of the fields with a class 'required'. I got it so I can add a red background to any field that fails the validation with the class required like so:

```
$("#signup_form").validate({
    errorClass: "validateError"
});
```

I have tried using the errorPlacement: function as others have mentioned to remove the error param like so:

```
$("#signup_form").validate({
    errorClass: "validateError"
    errorPlacement: function (error, elemenet) {
       error.remove();
    },
});
```

This just kills the validation entirely.

One forum mentioned that I need to specify each field that the validation could expect and override the default 'required' message to be nothing in the messages: function. How can I set it globally seeing as this setup needs to be dynamic to anticipate any field with a class required set to it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You are over-thinking this.   By default, the plugin adds class `error` to any element with an error.  It's that simple. Just target your CSS appropriately.

Comment: That ended up being part of the solution. The other problem was the default message for 'required' I was trying to remove it globally but still use the error class for controlling background color.

Comment: See complete answer below.

Answer (score 4):

To style elements that have validation errors, you would simply target the default class for errors with your CSS.  The default class is `error`.

```
.error {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

or perhaps more specifically:

```
input.error {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

---

To globally change validation error messages for this plugin, use this:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "your message here"
});
```

Reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457053/594235

---

To remove all error messages entirely, just place a `return false;` inside the `errorPlacement` callback function:

```
errorPlacement: function () {
    return false;
}
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/eP5HF/