# How does jQuery Validation setups the validation message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I wrote an additional method for jquery validation plugin that checks if a given value meets the length requirements defined along with the validation process.

So the method looks like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactLength", function(value, element, param){
    var len = value.length;
    if ($.isArray(param)){
        if (param.indexOf(len) !== -1){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (param != len){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}, jQuery.format("Value must have {0} characters"));
```

It works but the only problem is that message sent to the user doesn't meet my needs. The reason why is because one field might have more than 1 valid length.

A bank code can have 8 or 11 digits.
So, if I define the options below I expect the following output in case of error:
**"Please, the value must have 8 or 11 digits."**

```
{
"options":{
  "rules":  {
     "inputx": {
        "required":     true,
        "exactLength":  [8,11]
      }
   }
}
}
```

But I want more flexibility because i can have 2 values defined as valid lengths, **"Please, the value must have 8, 11, xxx or 23 digits"**
Or i can basic field where the input must have only 1 specific length **"please, the value must have 8 digits"**

**So, inside the method is it possible to tell want should be passed to the message?**

## EDIT:

**Added full solution based on Arun P Johny answer**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactLength", function(value, element, param){
    var len = value.length;
    if ($.isArray(param)){
        if (param.indexOf(len) !== -1){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (param != len){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}, function(param, element){
    var str = "";

    if ($.isArray(param)){
        var paramLen = param.length,
                lastParamValue = param[ paramLen - 1];

        if (paramLen == 2){
            str = param[0];
        } else {
            for(var i = 0; i< paramLen - 1; i++){

                if (i == paramLen - 1){
                    str += ',' + param[i];
                }   else {
                    if (i == 0)
                        str += param[0];
                    else
                        str += ',' + param[i];
                }
            }
        }

        return jQuery.format("Value must have {0} or {1} characters", str, lastParamValue );

    } else {
        return jQuery.format("Value must have {0} characters", param )
    }


});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery validation: change default error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457032/jquery-validation-change-default-error-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message option can be a function so

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactLength", function (value, element, param) {
    var len = value.length;
    if ($.isArray(param)) {
        if (param.indexOf(len) !== -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (param != len) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}, function (param, element) {
    //you can customize the string generation here, params refers to the array passed to the rule
    return "Value must have " + param.join(',') + " characters"
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5e225y1/)