# Jquery validation custom message not working for array based field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following code and it doesn't work with the custom messages, but it works with the default message. Jquery validation custom message is not working for `array based field name`.

```
$("#signup").validate({

ignore: "",
rules: {
"data[email]": {
    //cardCVC: true,
    required: true,
    email:true
},
"data[password]": {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
},
 "data[cpassword]":{
    required:true 
},
"data[captcha]":{
    required:true
}, 
// Specify the validation error messages
messages: {

   'data[email]':{
       required: "Please enter a valid email address"
    }
},

submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}


}

});



{{Form::open(array('url'=>'signup','method'=>'post','id'=>'signup','novalidate'=>"novalidate"))}}

    <label for="login_email" class="required">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="data[email]" id="email">
```

Could anyone help me to sort out the issue?
Thanks
AZ

Comment: Can you clarify the problem please ? What do you mean by `it doesn't working the custom messages but it works with default message.` ? what is the working code, and the not-working code ? What are the errors of the non-working code ?

Comment: the default message means ex: "This field is required." .The custom message means "Please enter a valid email address". Currently the above code works with the default message

Comment: Please check once what i given as an answer below.

Comment: What does PHP have to do with anything here?  Please do not tag-spam.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are not following the proper format of jquery validator custom message.Please do in following manner: --

```
rules: {
    'data[email]': {
        //cardCVC: true,
        required: true,
        email:true
    },
    "data[password]": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    }
  ,    "data[cpassword]":{

        required:true

    },
    "data[captcha]":{
        required:true
    }
},
messages: {

       'data[email]':{
           required: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
 },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }

});
```

Note:- for reference :- http://runnable.com/UkmCKF6ekb0tAAC-/how-to-use-jquery-validation-custom-messages-and-placement

If you want to change directly it's default messages with costume messages:-  [jQuery validation: change default error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457032/jquery-validation-change-default-error-message)

Comment: thanks anant .it works very well .i didn't check the curly brackets properly.