# Valid function with custom message

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery's `valid()` for a `form` submit, but it is displays a default error message. I want to display a custom error message for each field.

Custom error message is available for `validate()`, it's working.

I want display custom error message with the `valid()` function.

Sample code:

```
$("form").valid() {
    form.submit();
}
```

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="required">
```

This field is required - default error message.

I want custom message like "The Name field is required".

I have to validate around 25 inputs. Can I write code for each validate or any other solution?

Comment: you need to share your code.... with an example if possible http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jux0hs7v/2/

Comment: valid()
This method does not accept any arguments.

Comment: Visit following link and try.

1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457032/jquery-validation-change-default-error-message