# jQuery validate, different error message based on input type

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need change default error message of jQuery Validation [Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). I have learned how to achieve this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457053/6667390), and this working great. However i need some more customazation. Is it possible to set different error messages based on type of input field. 
I mean, for:

```
<input type="text" required>
```

default error massege should be "Filling this field is required". And for

```
<input type="file" required>
```

default error massege should be "Attaching document is required".
I know that I can set error messages separately for fields like this:

```
$('form').validate({                
    messages: {
        FieldName: { required: "Attaching document is required" }
    }
});
```

Problem is that, the form is really huge, so I thought writing separate error messages would not be good solution.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please say how many text boxes/file fields are there in your form ?

Comment: There are 9 different sized forms, overall i have almost 300 input fields, 48 of them "file" fields @SarojSasmal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `.rules('add')` method combined with a jQuery `.each()` to globally change the error messages based on `type`.

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        messages: {
            required: "this TEXT field is required"
        }
    })
});

$('input[type="file"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        messages: {
            required: "this FILE upload field is required"
        }
    })
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/cftesLwd/](http://jsfiddle.net/cftesLwd/)**

My demo shows that you can use this method to change the message even in cases where you don't use this method to declare the rule itself.  Messages only show up on fields that contain the `required` attribute.  Otherwise, [you can also easily declare the `required` rule for **all** inputs of these types](http://jsfiddle.net/cftesLwd/1/) even when you don't have the inline `required` attribute.

Answer (score -2):

Give each input field a different name and create validation rules individually for names

Suppose you have 2 fields:

```
<input type="text" name="textfield" required>
<input type="file" name="filefield" required>
```

then your validation messages will be:

```
var validator = $("form").validate({
rules: {
    textfield: "required",
    filefield: "required",
},
messages: {
    textfield: "Filling this field is required",
    textfield: "Attaching document is required",
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but please read question one more time. I've explained why given solution is not acceptable

Comment: I have 1 workaround for your situation. You don't have to declare messages for each field, but I suppose you have 'name' attribute has been set for all fields. Then loop through all fields, check the field types and build an object for the value of validator.messages. Something like that: `if (field.attr("type") == 'text' ) { msgObj[field.attr("name")] = "Filling this field is required" }` , after that: `validator.messages = msgObj;`

Comment: *"I have 1 workaround"* ~ No need; there's already a built-in method.  Also, when using the `required` attribute on the input, it's totally redundant and superfluous to also put the declaration within the `rules` object.