# how to replace default error message in jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a bunch of address inputs and I want to change the default `required` message in one go without typing each message for each input field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frm').validate({
        rules: {
            street: {
                required: true
            },
            city: {
                required: true
            },
            province: {
                required: true
            }, ...
        },
        messages: {
            required: "ASDSA"
        }, ...
});
```

I tried this code but it does not work. No response or effect from the browser whatsoever.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [jquery validation - change default error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457053/2181514)?  Or any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+change+This+field+is+required)?

Comment: The first one worked well, thanks for pointing that one out